# Как реализовать взаимодействие с USB-модемом на с++

Tags: модемы, c++

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как я могу управлять USB-модемом? На данный момент думаю, что это все происходит так:

1) при подключении модема к USB-разъему операционная система создает виртуальный com-порт;
2) узнаем номер порта через диспетчер устройств; 
3) подаем на необходимый com-порт AT команду;
4) считываем ответ USB-модема.

Правильно ли я понимаю принцип работы с модемом? Дело в том, что пробовал отправлять команду на com-порт по готовым примерам в Интернете, не получилось. В связи с этим прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Поддерживает ли USB-модем последовательный интерфейс? -- скорее всего, да. Распознаёт ли система данное конкретное устройство? -- необходимо проверить, например, `python -m serial.tools.list_ports` команда печатает список доступных портов. Как на C++ общаться с COM, может зависить от системы, например, [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).

Comment: К сожалению, программу под Windows нужно написать. Благодарю за информацию и наводки)